# HP Probook 4540s continuously flashes the HP logo without starting Windows

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

I was using my HP Probook 4540s when the screen turned black so I shut down the computer. When I tried to boot the computer back on the computer would flash the HP logo then the screen would go black. This cycle repeats itself forever every 5 seconds the logo is flashed back on the screen. The computer was running Windows 10 before this problem started occurring. I ran tests in Bios and the results were:

> Processor Check: PASSED Memory Test: PASSED Hard Disk SMART Check:
>   PASSED Hard Disk Short DST: PASSED Hard Disk Optimized DST: PASSED
>   Hard Disk Long DST: PASSED Battery Test: NOT INSTALLED WLAN Module
>   Check: PASSED PCI Device Check: PASSED Video Memoery Check: PASSED

When I used to boot the computer in the past I would get an internal battery warning. Could this problem be a result of the battery? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See if the NUM lock and CAPS lock leds are [blinking](https://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/content-webapp/document?docId=emr_na-c01732674), it could mean a problem has been detected.

Comment: Have you updated windows 10 insider preview.

Comment: @vembutech How can I do this if Windows does not start? Thank you for your response

Comment: @simlev The NUM lock and CAPS lock leds are not blinking

Comment: Try using Windows Installation disk to boot, and see if you can get to safe mode. More info here : https://www.groovypost.com/howto/create-windows-10-bootable-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: I am asking have you done before this issue occurred.

Comment: @vembutech No I did not update windows 10 insider preview